# Reading a file one int at a time in C++

Tags: c++, file-io

I am working on a program that requires reading in integers from a file into a 2D array. The concept is easy and I'm generally ok with file I/O. My problem is that the file contains 20 rows of 18 numbers. The numbers are not seperated by white space. An example is:

123456789987654321
192837465564738291

I have to read each individual number into the 2D array. I have created a for loop but I'm not getting the required output from the file I/O part of the loop. Is there a way to do this or do I need to use a work around such as reading the line into a string/array and dividing it? It's driving me mad. In the code, infile has been opened and tested. GRIDSIZE has a size of 9 and grid is the 2D array

```
int n;

for(int i=0; i<GRIDSIZE; i++)
      {   
    for(int j=0; j<GRIDSIZE; j++)
      {
        infile.get()>>grid[i][j];//This is causing the problem
         // infile >> n //Also tried this, not working
         // grid[i][j] = n;
        cout<<grid[i][j]<<endl;
      }
      }
```

Comment: So they are digits, and not numbers

Comment: @LucaMartini What's the difference?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_digit vs http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number basically numbers are composed of digits.

Comment: What is the type of `grid`?  Do you need conversion of the character to the corresponding integral value, or are you storing characters?

Comment: @JamesKanze I needed the integer for number operations. The answers below were what I needed thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling [get() on an ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/) returns a single character, casted to an int. So try changing

```
infile.get()>>grid[i][j];
```

to

```
grid[i][j] = infile.get();
```

That will give you the ASCII value of the digit. You can then use [isdigit()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isdigit/) (as noted by stefaanv) to make sure you actually have a digit, and then just subtract 0x30 (= 48 or '0') from them to get the integer values (as evident from an [ASCII chart](http://www.antrak.org.tr/gazete/062006/cizimler/tolga-tastan/ascii_table.jpg), the digits go from 0x30 to 0x39).
So for instance:

```
int n = infile.get();
if(isdigit(n)) {
  grid[i][j] = n - '0';
}
```

Comment: I did that and instead of getting 1 or 8 or 6 back I'm getting 50, 65 followed by some -1's and then it ends. It's not working correctly I'm still missing something

Comment: Having an additional problem. The loop runs perfect the first time but in subsequent runs it puts other numbers in front of what should be the first number of the loop. i.e. should be 123456789 but I'm getting 121234567 then 571212345 next time. What's causing this??

Comment: Well, you have a file with 20x18 numbers, but you seem to run your loop with GRIDSIZE iterations for both dimensions? Shouldn't you just run it 18 times for the inner-most loop? Also remember that you have newline/carriage return characters at the end of each line, so you probably need to handle that also (they should fail the isdigit() test though).

Comment: Sorry you were right about the loop iterations but I corrected that at an earlier stage. I was thinking that it must be to do with the way that it was dealing with the end of the line but I can't seem to get around it at all.

Comment: If you are reading the correct number of digits and then looping around, the next characters to read will be the newline/carriage return characters. You will need some code after the innermost loop to read these, and make sure that the infile-stream is advanced to the next line, before looping again.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [infile.get()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/) to get a character (as in sonicwave's answer) and check with [isdigit()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isdigit/) whether you actually have an integer digit.

**EDIT** (after comment from adohertyd):
If the ASCII character is a digit, you can subtract ASCII character '0' from it to get the actual number.